# How to rebuild Lustre Properly for MOFED

Tags: lustre

I've been struggling lately in how to get o2ib to function properly with a particular MOFED version. What I've tried so far is to install the Lustre kernel, rebuild MOFED for that Lustre kernel (which appears to be working) and then observe that ib0 is listed upon a reboot, and install the generic Lustre kmod-lustre kmod-lustre-osd-ldiskfs lustre-osd-ldiskfs-mount lustre lustre-resource-agents. However just because ib0 is there, does not  mean that o2ib presents itself in Lustre. Even running "lnetctl net add --net o2ib --if ib0" gives nothing but errors that the interface cannot be found.

I have tried rebuilding Lustre serveral times to try and get the o2ib interface, but to no avail. The rpms are built, but when I install them the situation is no better. My process is as follows (for Lustre 2.12):

git clone git://git.whamcloud.com/fs/lustre-release.git
cd lustre-release
git checkout 2.12.0
sh autogen.sh
./configure --with-o2ib=/usr/src/ofa_kernel/default/
make rpms

Would anyone have any suggestons?

Thanks!

Comment: Error: Package: kmod-lustre-2.12.4-1.el7.x86_64 (/kmod-lustre-2.12.4-1.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: ksym(ib_alloc_mr_user) = 0x1fb7fcc9
Error: Package: kmod-lustre-2.12.4-1.el7.x86_64 (/kmod-lustre-2.12.4-1.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: ksym(rdma_bind_addr) = 0x445a242e
Error: Package: kmod-lustre-2.12.4-1.el7.x86_64 (/kmod-lustre-2.12.4-1.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: ksym(rdma_listen) = 0xff8db636
Error: Package: kmod-lustre-2.12.4-1.el7.x86_64 (/kmod-lustre-2.12.4-1.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: ksym(rdma_destroy_id) = 0x7ea42958

Comment: The above is from the yum -y localinstall phase :

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should do the other way around: you should compile Lustre to properly use your MOFED and your kernel. This is the order of dependencies:

1. Your kernel (e.g: 3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64)
2. Your MOFED has to be compiled for your kernel. If your kernel is one of the ones available from Mellanox you just need to install the rpms or let the MOFED installer do it for you:

```
# ./mlnxofedinstall
```

If you're using a different kernel you need to recompile MOFED (you need to install kernel-devel for this) with support for your kernel:

```
# ./mlnxofedinstall --add-kernel-support
```

3. Last, you'll have to rebuild Lustre against your kernel (kernel-devel) AND your MOFED (mlnx-ofa_kernel-devel):

```
# ./configure --with-linux=/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64/ --with-o2ib=/usr/src/ofa_kernel/default/
```

Now your MOFED is ready to run on top of your kernel and your Lustre RPMs are ready to run on top of your kernel and the o2ib driver will use the symbols compiled for your MOFED.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it was step #3 which was causing me grief. When I rebuilt Lustre, I could not install it due to ksym errors. I'm tryin a workaround now, but don't know yet if it will work. I'm installing generic OFED (not MOFED) for the Lustre kernel. It seems to work so far. I'll update you.

Comment: That's usually because you're building Lustre with OFED drivers that don't fit what your system is running when the k2oiblnd driver loads. I suggest you check which OFED modules you are running (modinfo + rpm -qf). If you're running in-kernel OFED then it's simple: ```./configure --with-kernel=<your kernel-devel path> --with-o2ib=yes```